# How do I move the contents of a UITableViewCell prototype to its own class in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have created a cell prototype and I would like to move it to its own class. Why can't I just:

1) Change the custom class in the Storyboard for the prototype cell
2) Create an init method in the UITableViewCell class

When I do this, it says I need to add a:

````
```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```
````

What does this function do and why do I need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all because of two fundamental rules of the Swift language:

- Declaring a designated initializer cuts off inheritance of other initializers from the superclass; and
- When a class adopts a protocol that declares an initializer, this class and any subclass it may ever have must implement this initializer. Therefore, the class not only must implement the initializer, but also must mark it as `required`.

It turns out that UIView (from which UITableViewCell descends) adopts a protocol called NSCoding. And this protocol requires an initializer `init(coder:)`. None of that is your doing; UIView and NSCoding are declared by Cocoa, not by you. But that doesn't matter! By the laws of Swift, a UIView subclass must (by the second rule) either *inherit* `init(coder:)` or must explicitly *implement* it.

Well, as you just said, your subclass has implemented a designated initializer of its own — thus (by the first rule) *cutting off initializer inheritance*. Therefore it *must* implement `init(coder:)` *explicitly* and mark it `required`.

But of course, that makes no sense if you are not expecting `init(coder:)` ever to be *called* on your class. You are being forced to write an initializer for which you can provide no meaningful functionality! So you implement it anyway, but in order to escape the rules of what an initializer must do, you put in a `fatalError`.

Not only UIView but also UIViewController and *lots* of built-in Cocoa classes adopt NSCoding. You will encounter this problem if you subclass *any* of those classes and implement your own initializer. It's just something you have to get used to.

Answer (score -1):

That is the initialiser that is used if the cell is instantiated from Interface Builder.

While you may never be planning to use IB to create your cell, XCode doesn't know that and therefore requires the initialiser to exist so it can used if you were to.

Otherwise if at some point in the future you, or someone else, decided to use the tableViewCell for a cell in IB it would try and call the method and crash, so therefore it is made a required initialiser (even if it does nothing other than perform a controlled crash!)